# "An URL must be set" message while debugging OpenCTI Connector

Tags: python, security, url

im developing a small connector to understand how they work, When I execute run it on local I get this message : "An URL must be set"
Do someone have the same thing or know where does this error come?
My connector code is this :

```
# coding: utf-8

import os
import sys
import yaml
import time
import requests

from datetime import datetime
from pycti import OpenCTIConnectorHelper, get_config_variable
from stix2 import Indicator,Bundle

class blacklistIPConnector:
    def __init__(self):
        # Instantiate the connector helper from config
        config_file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/config.yml"
        config = (
            yaml.load(open(config_file_path), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
            if os.path.isfile(config_file_path)
            else {}
        )
        self.helper = OpenCTIConnectorHelper(config)

        #Extra config
        self.update_existing_data = get_config_variable(
            "CONNECTOR_UPDATE_EXISTING_DATA",
            ["connector", "update_existing_data"],
            config,
        )
        self.confidence_level = get_config_variable(
            "CONNECTOR_CONFIDENCE_LEVEL",
            ["connector", "confidence_level"],
            config,
        )
        self.blacklistIP_interval = get_config_variable(
            "BLACKLISTIP_INTERVAL", ["blacklistIP", "interval"], config, True
        )
        self.blacklistIP_url = get_config_variable(
            "BLACKLISTIP_URL", ["blacklistIP", "url"], config, False
        )

    def get_interval(self) -> int:
        return int(self.blacklistIP_interval) * 60 * 60 * 24
    
    def _collect_intelligence(self) -> list:
        time_now = datetime.now()
        current_time = time_now.strftime("%H:%M")

        print("The current date and time is :", current_time)
        url = 'http://api.blocklist.de/getlast.php?time='+current_time
        response = requests.get(url)
        self.helper.log_debug("websites response is : " + response)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            #data = response.text.splitlines()
            message = (
                f"{self.helper.connect_name} connector successfully retrieved data and converting it to STIX2 Format "
                + str(time_now)
            )
            #self.helper.log_info(message)
            ##Calling the stix transformer
            data_to_bundle = self.create_stix_objects(response)
            print("HELOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO THESE ARE THE DATA TRANSFORMED TO STIX :"+data_to_bundle)
            message = (
                f"{self.helper.connect_name} Formated to STIX2 bundle "
                + str(time_now)
            )
            self.helper.log_info(message)
            return data_to_bundle
        else:
            message = (
                f"{self.helper.connect_name} Failed to retrieve data on "
                + str(time_now)
            )
            self.helper.log_warning(message)

    def create_stix_objects(self, data):
        stix_objects = []
        for line in data.splitlines():
            timestamp = int(time.time())
            # Assuming each line contains an IP address and other data
            ip = line.split(',')[0]  # Adjust this based on the actual data format
            indicator = Indicator(
                pattern="[ipv4-addr:value = '{}']".format(ip),
                pattern_type="stix",
                valid_from="'{}'".format(timestamp)  # Adjust the timestamp as needed
            )
            stix_objects.append(indicator)

        return Bundle(objects=stix_objects).serialize()

    def process_data(self):
        try:
            # Get the current timestamp and check
            timestamp = int(time.time())
            current_state = self.helper.get_state()
            if current_state is not None and "last_run" in current_state:
                last_run = current_state["last_run"]
                self.helper.log_info(
                    "Connector last run: "
                    + datetime.utcfromtimestamp(last_run).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                )
            else:
                last_run = None
                self.helper.log_info("Connector has never run")
            # If the last_run is more than interval-1 day
            if last_run is None or (
                (timestamp - last_run) > ((int(self.blacklistIP_interval) - 1) * 60 * 60 * 24)
            ):
                self.helper.log_info("Connector will run!")

                now = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
                friendly_name = "blacklistIP run @ " + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                work_id = self.helper.api.work.initiate_work(
                    self.helper.connect_id, friendly_name
                )
                # Retrieve blacklistIP stix file
                if (
                    self.blacklistIP_url is not None
                    and len(self.blacklistIP_url) > 0
                ):
                    blacklist_data = self._collect_intelligence(self.blacklistIP_url)
                    self.helper.log_debug(blacklist_data)
                    self.send_bundle(work_id, blacklist_data)

                # Store the current timestamp as a last run
                message = "Connector successfully run, storing last_run as " + str(
                    timestamp
                )
                self.helper.log_info(message)
                self.helper.set_state({"last_run": timestamp})
                self.helper.api.work.to_processed(work_id, message)
                self.helper.log_info(
                    "Last_run stored, next run in: "
                    + str(round(self.get_interval() / 60 / 60 / 24, 2))
                    + " days"
                )
            else:
                new_interval = self.get_interval() - (timestamp - last_run)
                self.helper.log_info(
                    "Connector will not run, next run in: "
                    + str(round(new_interval / 60 / 60 / 24, 2))
                    + " days"
                )
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            self.helper.log_info("Connector stop")
            sys.exit(0)
        except Exception as e:
            self.helper.log_error(str(e))

    def send_bundle(self, work_id: str, serialized_bundle: str) -> None:
        try:
            self.helper.send_stix2_bundle(
                serialized_bundle,
                entities_types=self.helper.connect_scope,
                update=self.update_existing_data,
                work_id=work_id,
            )
        except Exception as e:
            self.helper.log_error(f"Error while sending bundle: {e}")

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.helper.log_info("Fetching BlacklistIP framework...")

        get_run_and_terminate = getattr(self.helper, "get_run_and_terminate", None)
        if callable(get_run_and_terminate) and self.helper.get_run_and_terminate():
            self.process_data()
            self.helper.force_ping()
        else:
            while True:
                self.process_data()
                time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        connector = blacklistIPConnector()
        connector.run()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(10)
        exit(0)
```

My config.yml.sample file is like this :

```
opencti:
  url: 'http://localhost:8080'
  token: 'changeme'

connector:
  id: 'changeme'
  type: 'EXTERNAL_IMPORT'
  name: 'blacklistIP'
  scope: 'attack-pattern' # MIME type or SCO
  confidence_level: 100 # From 0 (Unknown) to 100 (Fully trusted)
  log_level: 'info'
  update_existing_data: false
  run_and_terminate: false

blacklistIP:
  interval: 1 # in days
  url: 'http://api.blocklist.de/getlast.php?time='
```

Of course I changed the token and id on my local.
The code is getting some blacklisted IPv4 adresses using the url and then transform it to STIX Bundle and sends it to OpenCTI, it's a pretty much basic connector

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the URL has to be a url without parameter and ending slash.

Like, it should be something like `http://api.blocklist.de` from your example.